# How to map sales against purchases sequentially using python?

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, stock

I have a transaction dataframe as under:

```
     Item  Date        Code   Qty  Price   Value
0    A     01-01-01    Buy    10   100.5   1005.0
1    A     02-01-01    Buy    5    120.0   600.0
2    A     03-01-01    Sell   12   125.0   1500.0
3    A     04-01-01    Buy    9    110.0   990.0
4    A     04-01-01    Sell   1    100.0   100.0
#and so on... there are a million rows with about thousand items (here just one item A)
```

What I want is to map each selling transaction against purchase transaction in a sequential manner of FIRST IN FIRST OUT. So, the purchase that was made first will be sold out first.

For this, I have added a new column `bQty` with opening balance same as purchase quantity. Then I iterate through the dataframe for each sell transaction to set the sold quantity off against purchase transaction before that date.

```
df['bQty'] = df[df['Code']=='Buy']['Quantity']
for each in df[df['Code']=='Sell']:
    for each in df[(df['Code']=='Buy') & (df['Date'] <= sellDate)]:
        #code#
```

Now this requires me to go through the whole dataframe again and again for each sell transaction.

For 1000 records it takes about 10 seconds to complete. So, we can assume that for a million records, this approach will take a lot time.

Is there any faster way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are only interested in the resulting final balance values per item, here is a fast way to calculate them:

Add two additional columns that contain the same absolute values as `Qty` and `Value`, but with a negative sign in those rows where the `Code` value is `Sell`. Then you can group by item and sum these values for each item, to get the remaining number of items and the money spent for them on balance.

```py
sale = df.Code == 'Sell'

df['Qty_signed'] = df.Qty.copy()
df.loc[sale, 'Qty_signed'] *= -1 

df['Value_signed'] = df.Value.copy()
df.loc[sale, 'Value_signed'] *= -1 

qty_remaining = df.groupby('Item')['Qty_signed'].sum()
print(qty_remaining)

money_spent = df.groupby('Item')['Value_signed'].sum()
print(money_spent)
```

Output:

```
Item
A    11
Name: Qty_signed, dtype: int64
Item
A    995.0
Name: Value_signed, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Hey Arne. Thanks for the answer. The quantity works. But the value as per your solution provides sales less purchase value, i.e. net profit. What I need is the purchase value of balance items. (To use the example, the value answer should be 1230.)

Comment: Maybe I don't understand the data correctly, but I thought I had calculated the money spent overall, on balance, per item. Thus this can be thought of as the purchase cost for those items that you own in the end. I am somewhat confused by your example calculation. It seems arbitrary to split the remaining items between different past price levels the way you do. What am I missing?

Comment: That's an accounting rule @arne. Amount spent is the purchase value always. Amount received through sale is not set-off against the purchase cost for calculating balance value. That goes as profit and is reported separately.

Comment: I have also added a few solution approaches in the question, some that I have explored so far.